# How to get the bookflip effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, effects

Finally I found the effect I was looking for.
Sadly it is written as a java applet.

Do you know how can I get the same effect with JavaScript?

You can see the effect in the link below... it switches between pictures as though they where book pages:

http://javaboutique.internet.com/BookFlip/

Comment: Wow: "Upload Date: July 13, 2001"

Comment: Yep, no wonder it took me so much time to remember, where I saw it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason I could not see the applet:

Please tell me if this does the job for you:

http://clickheredammit.com/pageflip/

Good luck!

EDIT:

I found one more:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jFlip

See it working here:

http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/demo.html

Tell me if no of this suits you!

Comment: it's a beauty! Thanks alot....For other people that find this useful: if you need IE make sure you have the excanvasX.js and that you fix the path in your html file.

Comment: one last thing: You got me what I needed .Yet my js is poor and I'm looking for a way to loop the pictures: like onload(){call the click function}... in the jquery.js the .click(function() does the flip but I want to call it every 5 seconds ()... I knew how to make onload function on an html page but here the code is strange.

Comment: What you want is to start it without the click?

Comment: I dont need the click... I'd like to create a site homepage where 5 pictures goes in a loop with the effect you gave me: on load(pics[]=new pics;pic1=a.jpg;pic2=b.jpg while(true){showPic(pics(i++ mod numOfPics))}) ... I know the code will be different but that's the idea

Comment: Ok I can try no problem but please make of it another question because it is a whole different matter and so that Im not the only one trying to do this ok? Thanks!

Comment: I have been seeing and it is quite a modification, so for sure you would have to start another question try to make it a good one because SO hates whn people just throw the code and ask them to modify it :)

Comment: I don't know what is SO, but I agree with you- A person that ask someone for help should respect both his effort and time. Just to make sure... I've been looking for this for a very long time and I really appreciate your help... it's getting late here so I'll post my question tomorrow. thanks Asaf

Comment: SO = StackOverflow :) it is my pleasure to helo you out and will definitely continue to try. I just want to respect the site etiquette and make things more organized with future-commers. I´ll wait for your question tomorrow but start looking at the code today! See ya!